# How to not use :key=”$route.path” when I am in same username

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I faced a problem when I am in user profile and tried to go to another profile the URL change but the component doesn’t reload so I used `:key="$route.path"` in order to reload the component but there are problems each user profile have different URLs like about and photos and different things the problem is when I am in about and going to photos the component reload

**What my purpose**

how I can don’t use `:key="$route.path"` when I am in the same $route.params.username

My profile component

```
   <div class="profile-menu-top">
{{user.username}}
{{user.num_followers}} followers
  </div>

    <div class="profile-menu">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Account', params: { username:  $route.params.username}}" class="profile-menu-link ">Timeline</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'UserAbout', params: { username: $route.params.username }}" class="profile-menu-link ">About</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'MyAccount'}" class="profile-menu-link ">Videos</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'MyAccount'}" class="profile-menu-link ">Posts</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the router index

```
    {
path: '/u/:username',
name: 'Account',
component: Account,
},
```

The profile

```
<Profile v-if="userAccount" :key="$route.path" />
```

Comment: You could use vue-router's 'beforeRouteUpdate' in the Account component to trigger when you switch to a new user. I'd probably have `user` pass down as a prop from Account to Profile, instead of relying on a re-render with route params and getting the data in Profile, to prevent unnecessarily rerendering some DOM nodes plus being able to get the data before switching, saving you a loading screen. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: @Excalibaard  Can you please show me where I can add this because I am kind of nope in vue

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, if your answer is acceptable please mark it as chosen when you get the opportunity.

Comment: Ok, it will be available tomorrow to mark this answer as acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solved this problem by add `<Profile v-if="userAccount" :key="$route.params.username" />`

Thanks @ShayaUlman your answers helped me to solve problem

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, a simple solution will be to add the user id (or name) the the key:

```js
<Profile v-if="userAccount" :key="userAccount.id" />
```

Comment: @Ahmed, Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Hello it is still reload the profile component when navigate in user properties

Comment: So you **don't** want the component to reload when a user navigates within the profile? why not using just the id (or name) in the key? `:key="userAccount.id"`

Comment: Yes in same username params

Comment: it is don't reload the profile component but when I going to diffrent username the url change but the component didn't reload it still at the same username

Comment: It still same. It didn't reload the component when the username params change